# Xamarin.Forms 5.0 NavBar BackgroudColor not changing on IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, colors, xamarin.ios, navbar

I have this code in `AppDelegate.cs` function `FinishedLaunching` :

```
 UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor= Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor(); 
 UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor();
 UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = Color.White.ToUIColor();
 UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };
```

Before update Xamarin.Forms `4.8` to `5.0` this code worked for every navbar but now only show white color. `TintColor` and `TextColor` working fine. What should be the problem?
IMAGE:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color in Xamarin.forms when creating the NavigationPage:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()) { 
    BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("07987f"), 
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("07987f") 
};
```

I also see a thread in Github about this issue and you can wait the response there:

[UINavigationBar BackgroundColor can no longer be changed](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13291)

Comment: I added a picture. It is probably the last version of Xamarin. I will check this article everyday. If get fix i will write as an answer

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the problem in the latest version too. You can have a try with my codes as a workaround.

Comment: but with your code i must add on every page

Comment: No,  it's setting in the App.cs when creating the NavigationPage.

Comment: NavigationBar color changed after navigating?

Comment: Just on first page

Comment: OK, wait the response from the Github.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to specify it with Xamarin.Forms, using NavigationPage class.

It is certain that some code applies the color AFTER your code and thus you need to either disable it (if possible) or override it further down the line (as described above).

Comment: any sample u got?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 15, there is a known issue with the navbar color. You can override the default behavior by setting the color in your AppDeligate.cs file. This will affect every page:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    //A bug with iOS 15 results in the backgorund color not being set on the main appshell nav so we need to force it here
    var appearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance()
    {
         BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(144, 191, 110),
         ShadowColor = UIColor.FromRGB(144, 191, 110),
    };

    UINavigationBar.Appearance.StandardAppearance = appearance;
    UINavigationBar.Appearance.ScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
}
```

Both the StandardAppearance and the ScrollEdgeAppearence must be set the same. More info: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420